# How to keep ssh-agent always runnning on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, cron, rsync, ssh-agent

I'm trying to set up backing up some folder from one server (target server) to another (backup server) using rsync. I also need to call rsync from backup server so it's easier to maintain backup settings for multiple servers in one place.

To achieve this I am trying to add rsync command to crontab on backup server so my files sync periodically. The command looks like the following:

```
rsync -av --delete target_server_user@target_server:/path/to/directory/ /path/to/directory
```

As far as I know, rsync uses SSH for transport by default. When I run the command manually, it asks for password for the `remote_server_user`. While it's OK for one-time manual sync, it apparently doesn't allow for scheduled periodic sync using cron.

So I've created auth key pair on backup server with ssh-keygen, added created identity to target server with ssh-copy-id. But when I try to call rsync it asks for password. Then I found out that I need to add the identity to ssh-agent. And then I found out that the ssh-agent is not even running on backup server using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45841963/9594238).

Then I've launched it with `` eval `ssh-agent -s` ``, added the identity with `ssh-add path/to/identity`, checked that indentity is added with `ssh-add -L` and successfully run the rsync command above manually.

However after closing ssh connection to the backup server and connecting again as the same user, I get non-running ssh-agent. And when I start it I see no identities added in output of `ssh-add -L`. And as a result rsync command asks for password.

Is this a feature of ubuntu server (I have never had to launch ssh-agent manually on my ubuntu desktop)?

And when I fix ssh-agent and I add rsync command above to crontab, will it be able to use the identity added in `add-ssh` command? If ssh-agent and added identities are only available for the logged in user, it seems like I am going in wrong direction.

Or maybe there is a better way to set up periodic scheduled sync of directory?

I tried to set up rsync in daemon mode with creating all those `rsyncd.conf`, secrets and so on. But after successfully running that simple rsync command manually, it feels like it does what I need without lots of configuration. Except for non working ssh authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to set up sync by explicitly specifying path to identity file in `-e` flag as follows. The solution is even simpler than I wanted. In this case I don't have to think about managing `ssh-agent` and adding an identity.

```
rsync -ave "ssh -i /path/to/key" --delete target_server_user@target_server:/path/to/directory/ /path/to/directory
```

Helpful answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127355

Answer (score 1):

One work-around people typically use is to create a service specific ssh keypair that is not secured with a passphrase.

---

For security on the remote server you use the [extra **options** in the `~/.authorized_keys` file](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT) to place restrictions on what access is granted with that private key.

For instance options can vary from what ip-address access is granted with `from="10.9.8.7"` and you can restrict that only rsync can be started with `command="/bin/rsync"` and prevent interactive login sessions and such with `no-agent-forwarding,no-port-forwarding,no-pty,no-user-rc,no-X11-forwarding` and get an enntry that looks like:

```
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
command="/bin/rsync",from="10.9.8.7",no-agent-forwarding,no-port-forwarding,no-pty,no-user-rc,no-X11-forwarding ssh-rsa AAAxxxxx..more..public..key..data   Comment=This key can only be used for  remote backup
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I still can't run rsync command via crontab (and manually after logout) even with unrestricted ssh keypair.